# Adding the last position of an array to the same array

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

In matlab one can do

```matlab
for i = 2:10
 array(i) = array(i-1) + value
end
```

How can I replicate this in python?

Comment: I'm not very good at matlab, what is `value` here? Is it the old value of `array(i)`?

Comment: That's just a random value that we want to add to the array in each cycle.! I also don't understand this quite well. I was sent a Matlab script with this on it. Furthermore, I am trying to decipher it and implement it in python.
I believe that this is similar to the `array += value` where you have something like `k=k+1`

Comment: MATLAB can grow a matrix by simply assigning new indices. With `numpy` you need to initial the array to fill size first.  But we need more context to come up with a good `numpy` or python solution.  For example `np.cumsum([value1,value2, value3...])`.

Comment: Check out Manlais answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70560707/7031021

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python it will be:

```
for i in range(1,10):
   array[i] = array[i-1] + value
```

Keep in mind that in `python`, indexing starts from `0`.

Comment: Why `9`? If I understand correctly, matlab's `10` is inclusive, but `range` isn't, so you need `10` here to stop after index 9 (the 10th 0-indexed element)

Comment: @Expurple, You're right! Thank You for spotting it. Already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in python:

But you should also pay attention to one point:
That the number of indexes in Python starts from zero while in MATLAB from one

```
for i in range(2,10):
    array[i] = array[i-1] + value
```

have a good time!